# how to select element which is load by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I retrieve data by ajax method if user click on element with id="show". then I put id inside of `<table>`. my problem is after loading by ajax I want to delete each item `<i>` if someones click on it.

```
<script>
   $('#show').on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
                url:"index.php",
                method :"post",
                success: function(data){
                             for( var j in results){
                               var data = results[j];
                               $('tbody').append('<tr><td>'+data['name']+'</td><td>'+data['goods']+'</td><td>'+data['price']+'</td><td>'+data['date']+'</td><td><i id="'+data['id']+'" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></td></tr>'); 
                                 }
                            } 
                });
   });

</script>
<script>
  $('i').on('click', function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     $.ajax({
          data:id,
           url: "delete.php"
      });
  });
</script>
```

But unfortunately I can't remove with selecting `<i>`.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "_can't remove with selecting `<i>`_" ?

Comment: when user click on `<i>` first i get the id, then send it to server and delete it from database

Comment: ... ok and is it not deleting from database? or is it not getting correct `id`?

Comment: @MilanChheda, as I told you , id is undefined. no values has been set to id, so null will be sent to server and isn't deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your AJAX. You need to pass `data` in `{}`. Check below:

```
$('i').on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: 'delete.php',
    data: {
      id: id
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      // code here...
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: `<i>` will be created after user clicks on `<td>` with 'id=shown'.
in this case you and I wrote, on('click',function()... doesn't work

Comment: Where is `td` with `id=shown`? And even if `i` is created later, above code shall work. Did you tried? Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(document).on('click', 'i', function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     $.ajax({
          data:id,
           url: "delete.php"
      });
  });
```

Comment: the id is undefined.